# Appending url using jquery and preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, url, append

I'm trying to append a url with an id (just as a test) in my joomla installation using the following code.

```
jQuery('body').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = jQuery(this).attr('href') + '#test'; 
});
```

Now this works to an extent except it adds the string "undefined" right before "#test".

Example:

www.website.com/articles/undefined#test

Why is "undefined" being added, and is there a way to stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the body tag doesn't have an href attribute.  Use

```
window.location.hash = '#test';
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the body element, which does not have an "href" attribute.  So, your call to `.attr()` returns `undefined` which is converted to the string `"undefined"`.

If you just want to add "#test" to the url, you don't need to specify a complete URI.  Instead you can just specify the relative url, in this case "#test":

```
location.href = "#test";
```

If you are trying to append "#test" to a link in your document, you'll need to bind only to links with hrefs:

```
jQuery("a[href]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href') + '#test'; 
});
```

A couple other notes.  You don't need to use jQuery to get the href.  It would be simpler and more readable (IMHO) to just do:

```
location.href = this.href + "#test";
```

And, rather than preventing default and using javascript to do the navigation, you can just modify the href of the link:

```
jQuery("a[href]").click(function(e) {
    this.href += "#test";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the body tag doesn't have a `href` attribute. This is normally done for links i.e

```
<a href="some link">Link</a>
```